# Raspberry pi digital signage

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch

I am a newbie to the world of raspberry pi. I would like to display images as a slideshow on a screen connected to multiple raspberry pi. ( This is for the purpose of setting up electronic notice boards at various portions of the campus and hostels outside the campus)

I want to display the images from a particular folder as in Raspberry Pi. Also, I want to synchronise the contents of the folder with a folder on the cloud(Google drive/Dropbox)/ftp

I have gone through various digital signage methods, but couldn't find a suitable solution.

Can u please suggest a method? I have around 30 such screens (monitors connected to Raspberry PI)

Comment: what was wrong with the various methods you tried?  Will they all have internet access?   You could just host a webpage on a "master" RPI, and have all the other units just display that page, then you only have to host the imges on a single unit.